# Style based on value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have some inputs, such as:

```
<input name="binValue" value="Grey" type="hidden">
```

That are hidden. I would like to, based on the value of the hidden input, display a colored square instead of just simple text that says "Grey".

Like how Amazon displays the colored squares [here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_ex_p_n_size_browse-vebi_0?rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cn%3A7147442011%2Cn%3A1040664%2Cn%3A1045470%2Cp_89%3ABiscotti%2Cp_n_size_four_browse-vebin%3A1289878011%7C2662329011&bbn=1045470&ie=UTF8&qid=1406159208).

In their refinement on the left hand side.

The HTML that I'm using is:

```
<input name="binValue" value="Grey" type="hidden">
<a href="hostedbywebstore.com/s?field_color_map=Grey&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Csize_name%2Cbrandtextbin%2Ccolor_map%2Cprice%2Ccollection_name-bin&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Csize_name%2Cbrandtextbin%2Ccolor_map%2Cprice%2Ccollection_name-bin&amp;searchKeywords=*&amp;searchNodeID=5444386011&amp;searchRank=salesrank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow">                       
    <input type="checkbox">Grey    
</a>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add a CSS class

```
.Grey{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #CCC; /* or some other grey value you like */
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

change your checkbox

```
<input type"checkbox"><div class="Grey">&nbsp;</div>
```

you could also change it up so there is no check box and the div is the chackbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = $('input:hidden').val();
```

here you will get hidden input value, that is Gray

you write css like

```
.Gray{background:#ccc}
```

Than add class like

`$('a').addClass(color);` or

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').parent().addClass(color);
```